# JAVA - Request proxy from url

Tags: java, networking, proxy

I have a doubt that I would like to clarify.
I am programming in java and am trying to access a URL that has protected by proxy. I wonder if it was possible through URL know what are the proxy settings, then with this settings access to the URL through proxy.Regards

I think i don't explain myself clear.

In our browser options->lan setings, we can put there the proxy server with the port and host(and this a can access to this information with this code:)

' System.setProperty("java.net.useSystemProxies", "true"); System.out.println("detecting proxies"); List pl = ProxySelector.getDefault().select(new URI("http://google.pt/")); for (Proxy p : pl) System.out.println(p); Proxy p = null; if (pl.size() > 0) //uses first one p = pl.get(0); System.out.println(p.address()); System.out.println("Done"); '

But my problem is when i use the "automatic configuration script" and a put the path of the script. In this case a can't access to the proxy information. I try to do this in C# and i use the ' WebRequest.GetSystemWebProxy() ' and it works.

What i need to do to work in java?

Comment: What do you mean by "am trying to access a URL that has protected by proxy"?

Comment: A URL can't tell you your proxy server settings. You have to know that yourself, either by having set up the proxy yourself, or by asking your network administrator. Once you do know those settings, this link will help you connect to URLs through the proxy - http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0085.html.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot get proxy from an url, but you can get it from automatic configuration script (PAC) when you know the URL

- [Here](http://home.thorsen.pm/proxyforurl) is a website that parses/validates such scripts
- [Library](http://pacparser.manugarg.com/) to do so (python)
- [Blog post](https://medium.com/@jhaukur/java-proxy-pac-proxy-auto-config-f2b40e3785da) how to parse PAC in Java